# Customize a recurring PayPal Checkout's "A note from the seller"

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, recurring

Is it possible to edit or remove "A note from the seller" text inside paypal checkout? Or Is there a way to add custom CSS inside the paypal checkout?

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2lqF.png)

Comment: How is this integration done? Is it an HTML subscribe button or a smart button? Show the code / give details about your implementation

Comment: Its from here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/create-recurring-payments-profile-nvp/ 

I just need to remove that text, I'm not sure if there is an API value that will replace the text though.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the structure of this string in the language files of Opencart:

`public_html\catalog\language\en-gb\extension\payment\pp_express.php`

Original:

```
$_['text_recurring']          = '%s every %s %s';
```

The controller uses `sprintf()` to replace the placeholders with variables, so you may want to edit that too if you need access to more data. That file is here:

`public_html\catalog\controller\extension\payment\pp_express.php`

There are very, very long functions but you can search for 'text_recurring' and you'll find the `sprintf()` function there:

```
$recurring_description = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_recurring'), $recurring_amt, $item['recurring']['cycle'], $item['recurring']['frequency']);
```

Comment: Still didnt work though. I already tried this.

Comment: You haven't indicated which version of OpenCart you're using so it's very possible that the change is done but not visible. Did you refresh your cache after trying it?

Comment: Version 2.3 of opencart!